# How to split window with a Viewpager and Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to make something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the ViewPager is at top and window is spitted in a Viewpager and a Fragment.

I have tried following:

**activity_homescreen.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"


    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homescreen_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.krupalandharsh.touristguideexperiments.HomeScreenFragment" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_homescreen.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="login"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="signup"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**HomeScreenActivity.java**:

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity{

  ViewPager homescreen_viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);


        homescreen_viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_screen_view_pager);
        HomeScreenImageAdapter adapter = new HomeScreenImageAdapter(this);

        homescreen_viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

}
**HomeScreenFragment.java**:

```
public class HomeScreenFragment extends Fragment{


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homescreen, container, false);

                 return rootView;
        }
    }
```

**HomeScreenImageAdapter.java**

```
public class HomeScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;


    private int[] HomeScreenImages = new int[] {

            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image,
            android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now,
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer,
    };

    public HomeScreenImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return HomeScreenImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

       return (view == ((ImageView)object));

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){

        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);

        imageview.setImageResource(HomeScreenImages[position]);

        imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        ((ViewPager)container).addView(imageview);

        return imageview;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }


}
```

But, I can't see m below fragment. Only ViewPager is showing. Is there any idea you have by which we can split screen in Viewpager and Fragment as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other issues as well, but to start with, why not just use LinearLayout as the container, with proper equal weighting?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/home_screen_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homescreen_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    class="com.krupalandharsh.touristguideexperiments.HomeScreenFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with your xml of the homepage: "activity_homescreen".
You use relative layout for parent layout, but you also add parameter "weight" for both of two child layout, and one of it use 0dp width. 
Would you like to use "weight" to allocate the space for your viewPager and fragment?

I add and change some code and show it in the following. I change the parent layout to LinearLayout and add "weightSum". 
For The child layout I give 0dp for height, match_parent for width, and weight to allocate the height of them. You can chanage the parameters to fit your design.

I did not try it so I am not sure it will work. You can try it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"

    android:weightSum="6"

    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homescreen_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.krupalandharsh.touristguideexperiments.HomeScreenFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```